# Angular/Asp.net core 3.1 web.config issues

Tags: angular, web-config, asp.net-core-3.1

Adding the web.config with rewrite rules to an angular and aspn.netcore 3.1 web api is problematic from all angles.

The troubles I have been facing is for my sub routes e.g books/book/1 when working locally, refreshing this is not an issue. But on azure when hosted this fails and returns a 404.

To which I have read about handling redirect on the server. Problem when I add the web.config with rewrite rules as well as mimetypes.

This what the error reads: "**Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**"

The app doesn't even load.

take that way (the web.config) and re deploy. The app loads fine and you are able to navigate to a different url: books/book/1 but again reloading at this url will return a resource not found.

What do I need to make this work properly or an alternative without the need to rely on the web.config rewrite.

Using Asp.net core 3.1 web api
Angular 8

both these projects sit on separate repository, In the pipelines the contents of ng-build are extracted from the artifact and bundled into the wwwroot of the webapi project.

Overall, I want to resolve the reload issue but adding a web.config as other solutions have suggested has just been problematic in itself.

EDIT.

I came acrooss the azure static websites which may turnout to be an alternative to this but before I can consider using that as an alternative (no hash in the url)
I have configured my startup.cs the following way.

```
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {

            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/";
                await next();
            }
        })
         .UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" } })
         .UseStaticFiles();
```

the web config contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.bundle.js|.bundle.map|.bundle.js.gz|.bundle.css|.bundle.css.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico|.svg|.eot|.woff|\​.woff2)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".js" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With the above configuration when I deploy the app, I get this as a result in the network tab. We can see that out of all the responses. The main response and favicon have been successfully served but for the other angular resources all are failing.

[image]

What exactly could be causing this, is it angular 8 responsibility or is it caused by .net core web api.

Comment: are you using `{ useHash: true }` in your angular routing?

Comment: no. Perhaps if I enable it, this will add the # to the url. it could possibly solve the problem.

Comment: Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: nope but it will do for now as it solves the problem. the fact that every other solution I have attempted led to even more errors. will look into other ways of getting either angular 8 or .netcore 3.1 to work without the hash and refreshes successfully. Recommended approaches lead to one error after another. I guess for now it just doesn't work

Comment: Did you find a fix?  I have just encountered the same problem when I put the `web.config` file in my .NET Core app.  I moved `web.config` to the root directory (same as index.html) of my Angular app instead.  This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @Winthorpe depending on your architecture for example separating the UI (Angular) from the API (.net core) can lead to a few setbacks. Forget the webconfig n all that. This is the implementation that got me over the hurdle. 
`var pathValue = context.Request.Path.Value;
 if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                   !Path.HasExtension(pathValue) &&
                   !pathValue.StartsWith("/api/"))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
                }
`